# Getting Undefined Reference to Perl on C++

Tags: c++, perl, makefile

Well, first of all, sorry about my bad english!

I'm new to linux, g++ and perl, and I'm getting some problems here.

I have a code in G++ which calls a perl .pl file to return a information. Right now, I'm just returning 1 or 0 from the perl .pl file for tests and to understand how does it works. But the problem is that I'm getting this from the $make:

```
sathlervbn Spam C # make clean;make
rm -f *.o
g++  -Wall  -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -DDEBIAN -fstack-protector -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -I/usr/lib/perl/5.14/CORE   -c -o filedir.o filedir.cpp
g++  -Wall  -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -DDEBIAN -fstack-protector -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -I/usr/lib/perl/5.14/CORE   -c -o main.o main.cpp
main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**, char**)’:
main.cpp:112:41: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
main.cpp:112:41: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
g++ -L/usr/lib -Wall -Wl,-E  -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib  -L/usr/lib/perl/5.14/CORE -    lperl -ldl -lm -lpthread -lc -lcrypt -o main filedir.o main.o
main.o: In function `getInfoPerl(std::string)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x1a): undefined reference to `Perl_push_scope'
main.cpp:(.text+0x33): undefined reference to `Perl_save_int'
main.cpp:(.text+0x73): undefined reference to `Perl_markstack_grow'
main.cpp:(.text+0xcd): undefined reference to `Perl_stack_grow'
main.cpp:(.text+0xfa): undefined reference to `Perl_newSVpv'
main.cpp:(.text+0x10d): undefined reference to `Perl_sv_2mortal'
main.cpp:(.text+0x13b): undefined reference to `Perl_call_pv'
main.cpp:(.text+0x18f): undefined reference to `Perl_sv_2iv_flags'
main.cpp:(.text+0x1bd): undefined reference to `Perl_free_tmps'
main.cpp:(.text+0x1ca): undefined reference to `Perl_pop_scope'
main.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x206): undefined reference to `Perl_sys_init3'
main.cpp:(.text+0x20b): undefined reference to `perl_alloc'
main.cpp:(.text+0x21d): undefined reference to `perl_construct'
main.cpp:(.text+0x265): undefined reference to `perl_parse'
main.cpp:(.text+0x272): undefined reference to `perl_run'
main.cpp:(.text+0x2fd): undefined reference to `perl_destruct'
main.cpp:(.text+0x30a): undefined reference to `perl_free'
main.cpp:(.text+0x30f): undefined reference to `Perl_sys_term'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

The main.cpp code is:

```
#include <EXTERN.h>
#include <perl.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include "filedir.h"

using namespace std;  

PerlInterpreter *my_perl;

int getInfoPerl(string email){
    dSP;
    ENTER;
    SAVETMPS;
    PUSHMARK(SP);
    XPUSHs(sv_2mortal(newSVpv(email.c_str(),0)));
    PUTBACK;
    call_pv("spamTeste", G_SCALAR);
    SPAGAIN;

    int resultado = POPi;
    PUTBACK;
    FREETMPS;
    LEAVE;

    return resultado;

}

    int main(int argc, char **argv, char **env) {

    char *my_argv[] = { " ", "spamPerl.pl" };
    PERL_SYS_INIT3 (&argc, &argv, &env);

    my_perl = perl_alloc();
    perl_construct ( my_perl );
    PL_exit_flags |= PERL_EXIT_DESTRUCT_END;

    perl_parse(my_perl, NULL, 2, my_argv, (char **)NULL);
    perl_run(my_perl);

    cout << "Resultado " << getInfoPerl("email/email.txt") << endl;

    perl_destruct(my_perl);
    perl_free(my_perl);

    PERL_SYS_TERM();

    foobar bla bla bla another part from the code: doesn't matter.
}
```

Here is the makefile:

```
#CC= /usr/bin/g++
CPP = g++
CPPFLAGS = -Wall $(shell perl -MExtUtils::Embed -e ccopts)
#LD= /usr/bin/g++
LD = g++

LFLAGS = -Wall $(shell perl -MExtUtils::Embed -e ldopts)

#LFLAGS = -Wall -Wl,-E  -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib  -L/usr/lib/perl/5.14/CORE -lperl     -ldl -lm -lpthread -lc -lcrypt

MAINOBJS = filedir.o main.o

EMAILS = main

EXECS = $(EMAILS)

#Regra Implicita:
.c.o:
    $(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $<

all: emails

emails: $(EMAILS)

main: $(MAINOBJS)
    $(LD) -L/usr/lib $(LFLAGS) -o $@ $(MAINOBJS)

clean:
    rm -f *.o
```

What I did? I've tried installing libperl-dev package, update the perl, and nothing solved. 
I really need to fix this! Can someone help me?

UPDATE:

Changed the Header from main.cpp to:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
#include "EXTERN.h"
#include "perl.h"
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include "filedir.h"
```

Didn't work...

Comment: Only a hunch, but perhaps you need to put an `extern "C" {  }` around the perl header(s).

Comment: I don't know if Joe Z's fix is the correct one, but the problem is definitely the fact that you are looking for a C++ function instead of a C function.

Comment: Hum... As I saw, I've tried 

"#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
#include "EXTERN.h"
#include "perl.h"
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include "filedir.h""

But I still getting the problem.

Comment: Actually, looking a little more closely, those aren't name-mangled names... it is looking for the right C names, I think.  Looking more closely at the linking line, I see some extra spaces here, between the dash and the `l`: `-    lperl`.  Are those real, or is that an editing oddity?  I have to admit I'm grasping at straws a little, which is why I'm trying to help via comment rather than leaving a definitive answer.  :-)

Comment: It was just a problem while I was doing the 4 spaces to put as a code here. That part was the output from the terminal.

Comment: Anyone has no more ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the makefile:

```
#CC= /usr/bin/g++
CPP = g++
CPPFLAGS = -Wall $(shell perl -MExtUtils::Embed -e ccopts)
#LD= /usr/bin/g++
LD = g++

LFLAGS = -Wall $(shell perl -MExtUtils::Embed -e ldopts)

#LFLAGS = -Wall -Wl,-E  -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib  -L/usr/lib/perl/5.14/CORE -lperl     -ldl -lm -lpthread -lc -lcrypt

MAINOBJS = filedir.o main.o

EMAILS = main

EXECS = $(EMAILS)

#Regra Implicita:
.c.o:
$(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $<

all: emails

emails: $(EMAILS)

main: $(MAINOBJS)
    $(LD) -L/usr/lib $(LFLAGS) -o $@ $(MAINOBJS)

clean:
    rm -f *.o
```

As you can see, in this line, the code:

```
main: $(MAINOBJS)
    $(LD) -L/usr/lib $(LFLAGS) -o $@ $(MAINOBJS)
```

Should have the $(LFLAGS) after the $(MAINOBJS), so it should be:

```
main: $(MAINOBJS)
    $(LD) -L/usr/lib -o $@ $(MAINOBJS) $(LFLAGS)
```

Now, the linker is working perfectly. I'm sorry, but I can't say exactly why this is necessary, I've just discovered.

Comment: It's necessary because the linker does a single pass over libraries and object files. Whenever if sees a symbol, it asks itself "Have I seen a reference to this symbol that has not yet been resolved?" If the answer is "no", it discards it. If you list libraries before object files, of course all the library symbols are discarded (they have not been referenced by the `.o` files by the time they're seen).

Answer (score 3):

The answer previous is right, it is cause by the sequence of gcc parameters. I test a sample code provided by the official perlembed tutorial: 
http://perldoc.perl.org/perlembed.html

if the compile option is
        cc -o interp interp.c `perl -MExtUtils::Embed -e ccopts -e ldopts`
as provided by the tutorial, it is right.

But any other sequence is wrong, for example:
        cc interp.c -o interp `perl -MExtUtils::Embed -e ccopts -e ldopts`
        cc  `perl -MExtUtils::Embed -e ccopts -e ldopts` interp.c -o interp

so make sure in your Makefile -o goes the first and source file goes the second.